# how to install python package using tensorflow docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow docker image and running docker as 
docker run -p 8888:8888 -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow

which runs jupyter notebook and I can access it from my browser on port 8888.
The problem is I need to install a python package seaborn in this docker container. How can I do so.
I opened the terminal from jupyter notebook and tried installing using pip but it is not able to connect to internet.

I am using windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

After googling out I could find the solution. THe problem is with docker where containers cannot access the internet as DNS is not properly configured. I ran with --dns option in docker and it ran like a charm

here is the command for ref
docker run -p 8888:8888 -it --dns 8.8.8.8 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow